# Incorrect routing via /config/routes.php in symfony 6.1

Tags: symfony, symfony-routing

When I am defining routes in config/routes.php then those routes are not working in symfony 6.1

```
use App\Controller\BlogController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\Configurator\RoutingConfigurator;

return function (RoutingConfigurator $routes) {
   $routes->add('blog_list', '/blog/{page}') 
       ->controller([BlogController::class, 'list']) 
       ->defaults(['page' => 1])
       ->requirements(['page' => '\d+']);
};
```

Comment: For future reference, use three back ticks to format code blocks.

Comment: Make sure you don't have a config/routes.yaml file still hanging around.  It's kind of silly but you can have routes.yaml or routes.php but not both.  MicroKernelTrait::configureRoutes() shows the loading process.  And use `bin/console debug:router` to verify your routes.

Comment: Thanks, after removing routes.yaml it is working. Is there anyway to keep it both?

Comment: You can copy the configureRoutes method from the MicroKernalTrait to your src/Kernel class and tweak to your heart's content.